# Firebase Retrieve Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to display from data from my Firebase database show in Firebase Recyclerview , This my Database

[image]

And i try use the same as tutorial code from

[Firebase UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database)

I'm try and get this result
[image]

I'm fairly new to Android and programming in general, so any help would be appreciated. Here is the relevant code.

PostlistFragment

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = getActivity();

    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.NewDialog);
    mDialog.addContentView(
            new ProgressBar(mActivity),
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    );
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show();

    // Set up Layout Manager, reverse layout
    LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
    mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    // Set up FirebaseRecyclerAdapter with the Query
    Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostMainboard, MainboardViewHolder>(PostMainboard.class, R.layout.mainboard_list, MainboardViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        public void onDataChanged() {
            super.onDataChanged();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MainboardViewHolder viewHolder, final PostMainboard model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);


            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MainboardDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MainboardDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);
```

And result of my detail activity got same not show every one

[image]

Here My Detail Activity Code

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_mainboard_detail);

    mBodyView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_detail);
    mAuthorView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_author);
    mTitleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_topic);
    mDateView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.post_date_time);
    mCommentsRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_comments);
    mCommentsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mCommentField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_field);
    Button mCommentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_post_comment);
    mCommentButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Get post key from intent
    String mPostKey = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_POST_KEY);
    if (mPostKey == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must pass EXTRA_POST_KEY");
    }
    // Initialize Database
    mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("mainboard").child(mPostKey);
    mCommentsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cm-mainboard").child(mPostKey);


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Add value event listener to the post
    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            PostMainboard post = dataSnapshot.getValue(PostMainboard.class);
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            mAuthorView.setText(user.uid);
            mTitleView.setText(post.postTopic);
            mBodyView.setText(post.postDetail);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            Toast.makeText(MainboardDetailActivity.this, "Failed to load post.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);

    // Keep copy of post listener so we can remove it when app stops
    mPostListener = postListener;

    // Listen for comments
    mAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, mCommentsReference);
    mCommentsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mPostListener != null) {
        mPostReference.removeEventListener(mPostListener);
    }
    mAdapter.cleanupListener();
}
```

Post Class

```
public class PostMainboard{
public String uid;
public String auther;
public String postTopic;
public String postDetail;
public String postImageUrl;
public String postID;
private String postlatlon;
public long timeCreated;

public PostMainboard(){

}

public PostMainboard(String uid, String auther , String postTopic , String postDetail,long timeCreated)
{
    this.uid = uid;
    this.auther = auther;
    this.postTopic = postTopic;
    this.postDetail = postDetail;
    this.postImageUrl = postImageUrl;
    this.postID = postID;
    this.timeCreated = timeCreated;
}

@Exclude
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("mb_id", uid);
    result.put("mb_auther" , auther);
    result.put("mb_title", postTopic);
    result.put("mb_body", postDetail);
    result.put("mb_create", timeCreated);
    return result;
}
```

User class

```
public class User {
public String uid;
public String user_fname;
private String user_lname;
private String user_idcard;
private String email;
private String user_phone;

public User(){

}


public User(String uid ,String user_fname, String user_lname, String user_idcard, String email, String user_phone) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.user_fname = user_fname;
    this.user_lname = user_lname;
    this.user_idcard = user_idcard;
    this.email = email;
    this.user_phone = user_phone;
}
```

ViewHolder

```
public class MainboardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView authorView;
private TextView bodyView;
private TextView titleView;
private TextView dateView;

public MainboardViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    authorView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_author);
    bodyView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_detail);
    titleView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_topic);
    dateView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_time);
}

public void bindToPost (PostMainboard postMainboard)
{
    authorView.setText(postMainboard.auther);
    bodyView.setText(postMainboard.postDetail);
    titleView.setText(postMainboard.postTopic);
    dateView.setText((int) postMainboard.timeCreated);
}
```

Mainboard fragment

```
public  class MainboardFragment extends PostListFragment{


public MainboardFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    return databaseReference.child("mainboard").orderByKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten to populate the ViewHolder (MainboardViewHolder).

In "PostlistFragment" under "populateViewHolder" you need to call viewHolder.bindToPost(model) to bind the data to your textviews and so forth.

Try this:

```
    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final MainboardViewHolder viewHolder, final PostMainboard model, final int position) {
        final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

        viewHolder.bindToPost(model);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, MainboardDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MainboardDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postRef.getKey());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Also, your getQuery method is abstract and empty. It should probably look like this:

```
@Override
public Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
    return databaseReference.getReference("mainboard").orderByKey();
}
```

I'm saying "probably" because I can't see how you have initialized mDatabase. In the future, please paste complete code if you wan't better and faster answers.

Comment: I think not like this sir i need to show data im try to your code but cant

Comment: My code just provides a context and is intentionally left incomplete. But if you post the code for MainboardViewHolder.java I can give you a complete example.

Comment: Aah, yes! I don't know how I could miss that! My post is now updated. This should solve your first problem.

Comment: im try to add bindToPost i get empty not show anything

Comment: I've update my answer again. But please, include complete and runnable code here if you want better answers.

Comment: im post completed sir plz check

Comment: You've added the getQuery method to the wrong class. You are supposed to exchange get abstract getQuery method with my getQuery code. And also. - If you need any further help I need you to update your post with the complete code for all your classes. Not just a few methods.